# write multiple lists to csv (one is a nested list)

Tags: python, list

I have say three lists, and one of them is nested like so:

```py
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = ["abc", "def", "dec", "erf"]
c = [[5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13.3], [14, 15, 16]]
```

I would like a `CSV` file output of it which looks like this:

```
1,abc,5,6,7
2,def,8,9,10
3,erf,11,12,13.3
...
```

I tried zipping them and writing to a `CSV` file like so:

```py
with open('filer.csv', "w") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for row in zip(a, b, c):
        writer.writerow(row)
```

but the output has these stupid brackets like so:

```
1,abc,"[5,6,7]"
2,def,"[8,9,10]"
3,erf,"[11,12,13.3]"
...
```

but I want them without brackets and without the quotes like so:

```
1,abc,5,6,7
2,def,8,9,10
3,erf,11,12,13.3
...
```

:(

Comment: Perhaps `c` should use `','.join(c)`.  So unpack the `zip` into individual varaibles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
with open('filer.csv', "w") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for ai, bi, ci in zip(a, b, c):
        writer.writerow([ai, bi, *ci])
```

**Output**

```
1,abc,5,6,7
2,def,8,9,10
3,dec,11,12,13.3
4,erf,14,15,16
```

As you said you have nested list, so you need to flatten the list, the expression `[ai, bi, *ci]`  flattens it.

The reason that you get the brackets is that [`writerow`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerow) is (probably) applying the function [str](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str) for each element of the iterable passed to it. And the string representation of a list includes the brackets, for example:

```
In[3]: str([1, 2, 3])
Out[3]: '[1, 2, 3]'
```

Comment: thank you for solving this for me - I just spent 2 hours on this - I should really quit being a programmer! Thank you again.

Comment: @JohnJ Glad I could help!