# Python: write set of lists (1 nested list) to csv file

Tags: python

I have a set of data with two lists. list_2 can have any number of nested lists in it (which is where my problem stems from).

```
list_1 = [2000.0, 2100.0, 2200.0]
list_2 = [[-1.86, 0.49, 1.36], [-1.29, 0.59, 1.62], [-.99, 0.19, 1.76]]
```

once in the csv file it should look like

```
2000    -1.86    -1.29    -.99
2100    0.49    0.59     0.19
2200    1.36     1.62     1.76
```

I have tried a few different ways of writing the file

```
    with open(file_name, 'w') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerows(zip(list_1, list_2))
```

I've also tried zipping them before as see in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69647930/write-multiple-lists-to-csv-one-is-a-nested-list)

I've also tried separating the lists (in list_2) but that does not allow for any growth. I do not know the number of nested lists before running the application so it has to be able to grow.

```
writer.writerows(zip(list_1, list_2, list_3, list_4))  # does not allow for dynamic growth
```

Comment: show how should look csv for a more deeper nesting, say 4 levels

Comment: If you don't know the number of lists, you should be using a *list* of lists, not individually numbered list variables.

Comment: @chepner Yes that's what I'm trying to do. The last example was just to show what I have tried and what didn't work for me

Comment: `zip(*list_of_lists)`?

Comment: One place to start is `zip(list_1, list_2)`. This will give you a list of tuples where each tuple contains a number and a list. Now you will need to transform the tuples into a single list.

Comment: You have a list of data in column-major format. `csv.writerows` can write a row-major list-of-lists. You can do this by transposing your data. Does this answer your question? [Transpose list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473679/transpose-list-of-lists) (just do `col_data = [list_1, *list_2]` first)

Comment: In each case pay attention to add __newline=''__ in order to avoid empty rows: with open(file_name, 'w', newline='')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the `*` operator:

```
zip(list_1, *list_2)
```

This will create a list of lists where the first element of each sub list comes from `list_1` and the remaining elements come from each of the lists in `list_2`.

Answer (score 3):

if I get you right you don't know how many lists you are going to have. But all of them will have the same size?

And you want them to be stored "vertically"?

I have the feeling a [**transpose**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html)
operation would help you very well.

```
import csv
import numpy

list_1 = [2000.0, 2100.0, 2200.0]
list_2 = [[-1.86, 0.49, 1.36], [-1.29, 0.59, 1.62], [-.99, 0.19, 1.76]]

list_3 = [list_1] + list_2
output_array = numpy.transpose(numpy.array(list_3))

with open(file_name, 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerows(output_array)
```

Comment: @PranavHosangadi for me it is mostly enough to get an idea how to solve a situation.
But if you ask I will extend the answer ;-)